# Jquery Star Rating Plugin - how to make the hover tips stick after clicking

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-hover

I'm using this [jQuery Star Rating plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing)

It's working, but I"m trying to get the hover tip to stay on the page after I click.  Currently it disapears after you click and move the mouse away.

```
<script> 
$(function(){
 $('.hover-star').rating({
  focus: function(value, link){
    var tip = $('#hover-test');
    tip[0].data = tip[0].data || tip.html();
    tip.html(link.title || 'value: '+value);
  },
  blur: function(value, link){
    var tip = $('#hover-test');
    $('#hover-test').html(tip[0].data || '');
  }
});
</script>

<form id="ratingform">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="10"> 
<tr><Td>Hover over the stars and then click</td></tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="">
<div class="Clear">
<div>
<input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="rating" value="1" title="Very poor"/>
<input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="rating" value="2" title="Poor"/>
<input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="rating" value="3" title="OK"/>
<input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="rating" value="4" title="Good"/>
<input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="rating" value="5" title="Very Good"/>
<span id="hover-test" style="margin:0 0 0 20px;"></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "callback" function and use the same code as in the "focus" function. The "callback" function is executed when a star is clicked:

```
$(function(){
 $('.hover-star').rating({
  focus: function(value, link){
    ..
  },
  blur: function(value, link){
    ..
  },
  callback: function(value, link){
    var tip = $('#hover-test');
    tip[0].data = tip[0].data || tip.html();
    tip.html(link.title || 'value: '+value);
  }
});
```